# Custom JCombobox model with two toString methods

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a pretty similar problem like this one [Java ComboBox Different Value to Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387932/java-combobox-different-value-to-name)

I have already changed the code, so I'll get a `Employee`-Object (i changed my classnames, since the classnames in the link above are `Employee`).

In my case, I have already a `toString()` method, which I don't want to overwrite. (I need it somewhere else)

But I don't want to use this `toString()` method in my `JCombobox`. But it does automaticaly.

I don't want to return any strings! I need the objects.

Is there a way to say "take another `toString()` method, let's say `toStringDifferent()`" while creating the JCombobox?

```
this.comboEmployees = new JComboBox(new EmployeeComboboxModel(getEmployees())); 
// this will give me the toString-method's return-value of the Employee object. 
// But i want the toStringDifferent() method's result.
```

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact it is even considered good practice *not* to use `toString`.

```
comboEmployees.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                               Object value,
                                               int index,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Employee employee = (Employee)value;
        value = employee.toStringDifferent();
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
                index, isSelected, csellHasFocus);
    }
});
```

Comment: works great for me. 
somehow i get a nullpointer (i think for the first or last entry). I did a if(employee != null) arount the "value = employee.toStringDifferent();" and it worked.

Comment: @Joop: "In fact it is even considered good practice not to use toString." Says who?

Comment: @splungebpb I once gave an answer using `toString` and got a criticizing comment, saying just that. I do not think that is an iron rule, and would use what is most opportune. But I concede that writing a toString just for display in a JComboBox is not good style too.

Comment: @Joop: I would consider it more of a personal preference depending on the situation. I've used the custom renderer approach a few times for some very specific needs, but in general, writing a custom renderer for every combo in my app that casts to a specific object type seems crazy.

Comment: @splungebob, we evidently share the same programming style/laziness. But here an extra renderer fits.

Comment: If you would like to keep you combo filled with `Employee`, not `String`, you should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388036/2761418) answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListCellRenderer`. An example can be found int [the Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

An alternative is to wrap your objects inside an object defining its own `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your JComboBox and implement your toString method.

Example:

```
public class        MyComboBox
    extends     JComboBox
{
  public String toString() {
    return "My toString";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question ;)